# how do you "paste" with drag and drop TransferHandler?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

[image]I have this:
and want the image SD to be able to be draged and dropped into another JLabel (the JLabel now shows the picture SD), how would I do it?

```
    ImageIcon SD = new ImageIcon("resources/terrains/StoneDungeon.jpg");
    JLabel dns=new JLabel( SD);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dns);
    dns.setBounds(800,150,50,50);
    dns.setFont(new Font("Courior", Font.BOLD, 25));
    dns.setForeground(Color.red);
    final String propertyName = "text";
    dns.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(propertyName));
    // Listen for mouse clicks
    dns.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent)evt.getSource();
            TransferHandler th = comp.getTransferHandler();


            // Start the drag operation
            th.exportAsDrag(comp, evt, TransferHandler.COPY);
```

Please don't tell me to look at the tutorial, I already have.

I dont have enough rep to answer my question so here is the answer:

That was the stupidist mistake ever!!!!!!!!

code shoul've been:

```
        ImageIcon SD = new ImageIcon("resources/terrains/StoneDungeon.jpg");
    JLabel dns=new JLabel( SD);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dns);
    dns.setBounds(800,150,50,50);
    dns.setFont(new Font("Courior", Font.BOLD, 25));
    dns.setForeground(Color.red);
    dns.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(SD));
    MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            JComponent jc = (JComponent)e.getSource();
            TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
            th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
        }
    };
    dns.addMouseListener(ml);
```

I had put some string variables in instead of a picture to be moved!!!!
but now the problem is, you cant drag drop icons (SD)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to refresh the display when the drop operations is complete?

Comment: how do i refresh the display?

Comment: by using the method repaint of JPanel

Comment: could you give the actual code like JPanel.whatever.repaint?                 i'm a beginner in java so I don't understand what you are saying, thanks. I went on the API and didn't understand a thing.

Comment: you should add `frame.repaint();` after the drop operation is complete

Comment: um... That didn't work for me, any other ideas? (nothing happened at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageIcon SD = new ImageIcon("resources/terrains/StoneDungeon.jpg");
JLabel dns=new JLabel( SD);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dns);
    dns.setBounds(800,150,50,50);
    dns.setFont(new Font("Courior", Font.BOLD, 25));
    dns.setForeground(Color.red);
    dns.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
    MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            JComponent jc = (JComponent)e.getSource();
            TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
            th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
        }
    };
    dns.addMouseListener(ml);
```